# Access upload progress through http request in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Is it possible to measure file upload progress by accessing the http request in PHP? And if so how do i do it while uploading a file into a MySQL DB?

```
    require('../connect_db.php');
    //Gather all required data
       $name = $dbc->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']
      ['name']);

      $data = $dbc->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']
        ['tmp_name']));

      $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

      //create the sql query

      $query = "INSERT INTO `".$user."`(
              name,size,data,created
              )
              VALUES (
               '$name','$size','$data',NOW()
               )";
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php `$_FILES` means the file is already uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

For file upload with client side progress I would suggest to use something like this with jQuery plugin-

http://runnable.com/UZKDAYo3XEw2AACX/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-for-php

And I don't think storing files in DB, especially MySQL is good idea.